# Android Check current date with previous date saved in SharedPreference

Tags: android, datetime, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I have this method below that sends messages from users device to a server. I want to save the date i sent the messages to the server in SharedPreferences and check if new messages come in and they are current than the date in the SharedPreference then i send those messages. How do i go about it.

I updated my question with how i check the date but i realize that the method for checking the date is not working because anytime i call this method the messages already uploaded to server keep uploading but i only want them uploaded once unless a new message comes in.

```
private void startSync() {
    Uri mSmsinboxQueryUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(mSmsinboxQueryUri,new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date","body", "type" }, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor1);
    String transaction = "";
    String[] columns = new String[] { "address", "person", "date", "body","type" };
    if (cursor1.getCount() > 0) {
        String count = Integer.toString(cursor1.getCount());
        while (cursor1.moveToNext()){
            String address = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[0]));
            String name = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[1]));
            Date date = new Date(cursor1.getLong(0));
            formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").format(date);
            //date = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[2]));
            String msg = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[3]));
            type = cursor1.getInt(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[4]));
            status = 1;
            CreatedBy = userName;
            ModifiedBy = userName;

            if (address.equals("MobileMoney")){

                transaction += msg;

                long MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
                long updDate = prefs.getLong("lastupdate", 0) / MILLIS_PER_DAY;
                long currdate= System.currentTimeMillis() / MILLIS_PER_DAY;
                if (!(updDate == currdate)) {
                    saveExternalTransactions(userId, type, status, transaction, formattedDate, CreatedBy, ModifiedBy);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    editor.putLong("lastupdate", currdate);
                    editor.commit();
                }

            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: I cant understand what is the problem. You don't know how to save date into shared prefereces? Or how to compare dates? Or what?

Comment: @VladMatvienko i updated my question so you understand what i meant

Comment: You are comparing the wrong dates. !(updDate == currdate) is always true.

Comment: @AlexandreBOURETZ how do i compare the dates correctly

Answer (score 0):

you need to replace this line

```
long updDate = prefs.getLong("lastupdate", 0) / MILLIS_PER_DAY;
```

to this :

```
long updDate = prefs.getLong("lastupdate", 0);
```

it corrects your problem